# Making ToJSON use Show Instance

Tags: haskell, aeson

If I have a data type that looks like this:

```
data SumType = ABC | DEF deriving (Generic, ToJSON)
data MyType = MyType {field1 :: String, field2 :: SumType} deriving (Generic, ToJSON)
```

The above will generate a JSON that looks like: `{"field1": "blah", "field2":"ABC"}`

In practice, `MyType` is a fairly complex type and I would like to keep the `ToJSON` deriving but want to adjust just one field to use the show instance.

```
 instance Show SumType where
   show ABC = "abc-blah"
   show DEF = "def-xyz"
```

Unfortunately, the above `Show` instance does not get picked up by `ToJSON` (I don't know if it is supposed to).  Hand rolling `ToJSON` for `SumType` does not *seem* to work because it expects a key-value pair (Maybe there is another of way doing it?). In other words, the JSON will be like: `{"field1": "blah", "field2":{"field3": "ABC"}}` -- I just want to change the way the value is stringified and not create a new object there.

Any suggestions on how I can change the output string of `SumType` without manually creating `ToJSON` for `MyType`? So the output is  `{"field1": "blah", "field2":"abc-blah"}`

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with creating a `ToJSON` for `SumType`? You can use the definition in `Show SumType`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I thought `ToJSON` only accepts `objects`. I did not realize I can just return a string.  If you put your response in the answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see what the problem is with defining a `ToJSON` instance for the `SumType`. You can do this with:

```
import Data.Aeson(ToJSON(toJSON), Value(String))
import Data.Text(pack)

instance ToJSON SumType where
    toJSON = String . pack . show
```

Or if you want to use other strings for the `ToJSON` than `Show`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson(ToJSON(toJSON), Value(String))

instance ToJSON SumType where
    toJSON ABC = String "ABC for JSON"
    toJSON DEF = String "DEF for JSON"
```

Now Haskell will JSON-encode the `SumType` as a JSON string:

```
Prelude Data.Aeson> encode ABC
"\"ABC for JSON\""
Prelude Data.Aeson> encode DEF
"\"DEF for JSON\""
```

You can do the same with `FromJSON` to parse the JSON string back into a `SumType` object:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson(FromJSON(parseJSON), withText)

instance FromJSON SumType where
    parseJSON = withText "SumType" f
        where f "ABC for JSON" = return ABC
              f "DEF for JSON" = return DEF
              f _ = fail "Can not understand what you say!"
```

If we then parse back the JSON string, we get:

```
Prelude Data.Aeson> decode "\"ABC for JSON\"" :: Maybe SumType
Just ABC
Prelude Data.Aeson> decode "\"DEF for JSON\"" :: Maybe SumType
Just DEF
Prelude Data.Aeson> decode "\"other JSON string\"" :: Maybe SumType
Nothing
Prelude Data.Aeson> decode "{}" :: Maybe SumType
Nothing
```

So in case we do not decode a JSON string that follows one of the patterns we have defined, the parsing will fail. The same happens if we do not provide a JSON string, but for instance an empty JSON object.

> **Additional notes**:
>
> 1. Since `SumType` here has two values, you can also use a JSON boolean to encode the values.
> 2. you can also encode on different JSON objects. You can for instance use the JSON string for `ABC`, and an integer for `DEF`.
>      Although I would advice not to do this until there are good reasons
>      (if for instance `ABC` carries only a string, and `DEF` ony an
>      integer).
> 3. usually the more complex you make encoding, the more complex decoding will be.

Comment: What does `"SumType"` passed to `withText` do? Change the failure message when parsing some other way? That might be good to demonstrate.